# rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred

Tags: debian, centos, email, rsync, migration

I'm trying to move my emails `Maildir` from an old CentOS server to a new Debian server.

```
rsync -avz /home/me/Maildir ssh root@ipaddress:/var/vmail/me/Maildir
```

I tried to copy a 8GB account, didn't work, try to move another about 20mb, didn't work, tried to use `-avn`, didn't work either.

```
sync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Comment: What do the previous errors say?

Comment: @jordanm there's no previous error, it just says that there's a previous error, but i haven't seen any error

Comment: If you have a large log file and can't spot the error, I found searching for the string `rsync:` would turn it up.

Comment: Thank you @duozmo ! I was searching for "error" like an idiot. Why did I think that errors would state themselves as "errors" anyway? XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error 23 is defined as a "partial transfer" and might be caused by filesystem incompatibilities, such as different character sets or access control lists. In this case, it could be caused by files in `/home` that begin with a `.` and are thus marked hidden.

In this case you could try something like:

```
rsync -avz --exclude='/*/.local' /home/me/Maildir ssh root@ipaddress:/var/vmail/me/Maildir
```

The verbose argument -v should actually give you some sort of list of the problems.

From [official documentation](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#EXIT_VALUES):

> - **23** -⁠ Partial transfer due to error

Comment: the above line gave the same error

Comment: The above line was meant as an example how to exclude one hidden directory, if you have more you probably have to adjust the line.

Comment: i needed to changed the permissions of the directories as well

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing one or a combination of `--perms --no-owner --no-group`. This allows you to copy / override source permissions on the destination, while `--no-owner` and `--no-group` ignore owner and group permissions respectively (which can be likely since the destination may not know that user & groups).

If you'd like to override those permissions for the target system, use `--chmod=ugo=,u+rwx,g+rw,o+r`. In this example I gave the executing User / Owner `rwx`, his Group `rw` and Others `r` (Initial `ugo=,` unsets all flags).