# rsync copy failed Input/output error (5)

Tags: rsync

I've seen this
[rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72259/rsync-error-some-files-attrs-were-not-transferred)

Seems like it's telling me to rename something before copying it to a different server drive, But can't Rsync do the rename itself and then copy?
Log:

```
rsync: [receiver] rename "/content/memes/My Laptop/My Laptop/Gallery/Memes/Vid/.\#360\#237\#245\#264\#360\#237\#245\#264\#360\#237\#245\#264 ( Source ).mp4.Bl8ZHR" -> "My Laptop/Gallery/Memes/Vid/\#360\#237\#245\#264\#360\#237\#245\#264\#360\#237\#245\#264 ( Source ).mp4": Input/output error (5)
sent 1.63M bytes  received 121 bytes  251.13K bytes/sec
total size is 9.56G  speedup is 5,858.29
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1333) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Comment: It's not telling you to rename anything. It's telling you it can't set the name of a particular file on the target filesystem, probably because the filename contains special characters that the target filesystem can't cope with.  Are you writing to an MSDOS, FAT, or NTFS filesystem?

Comment: Yes, I got that much, but can't Rsync make a valid rename and copy the file?

The drive was created by,
```
!mkdir $local_mount_location 2>/dev/null
# !mkdir $local_mount_location
!nohup rclone mount $rclone_config_name: $local_mount_location &
```